# WEPopover does not work with UIViewController != UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, popover

I use WEPopover (https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover) to display popovers on iPhone. Unfortunately it does not work if I use a general `UIViewController` for the `contentViewController` of it.

```
- (IBAction)showPopover:(id)sender
{
    UIViewController *contentViewController = [[PopoverContentViewController alloc] init];
    popoverController = [[WEPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:contentViewController];
    popoverController.delegate = self;
    [popoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:(UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp) animated:YES];
}
```

This just presents me a black popover with no content. The `PopoverContentViewController` is just a normal UIViewController generated by XCode without any changes to it. In my storyboard I added a ViewController, set its size to freeform and set the view's size to something lower than standard iPhone size. I set the owner of this viewcontroller the `PopoverContentViewController`. Unfortunately it does not show the content, it just shows a black popup.

If I change the the `PopoverContentViewController` to derive from `UITableViewController` it shows a table view, but that is not what I want.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You likely need to load your view controller from the storyboard instead of instantiating it with alloc/init as you show.

Something like this:

```
UIViewController* contentViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName: @"yourStoryboardName" bundle: nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"yourViewControllerID"];
```

Comment: Thx, that's it! The controller now gets displayed. But in my storyboard the controller is freeform and the containing view is set to 220x135 points of size. Unfortunately the popover is much bigger, almost the whole iPhone size. Why? And the arrow is out of screen, you only see a little bit of it.

Comment: @tester - in code, set your content view controller's contentSizeForViewInPopover property to the correct CGSize value.  You need to do this before it is presented (WEPopover doesn't monitor the value for change after presentation)